# how do I install an npm package (math-simple-integrals)

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, npm, project

Hello I have been trying to install the npm package 'math-simple-integral'
and I am having trouble making it work, I originally used math.js and just used the cdnjs script src

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.0/math.min.js"></script>
```

and that worked for all of the functions that I needed but it didnt work for the math.integral() function that I am looking for I am not sure how to install 'npm install mathjs-simple-integral' and I am wondering if there is a script src that I can use like I did for the math.js.

any assistance would be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to run `npm install`, you must first install **[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)**.

You then run `npm install mathjs-simple-integral` from the command line at the root folder of your project. This will create a `node_modules` folder which contains the JavaScript files you want to link to.

Then you would reference it with something like:

```
<script src="node_modules/mathjs-simple-integral/index.js"></script>
```

However, you'd probably want to use something like Gulp, Bower or WebPack to include your dependencies.

Then you can simply reference it by importing it to `math`:

```
math.import(require('mathjs-simple-integral'));
```